# WPF usando MVVM - De quem é a responsabilidade de abrir uma nova janela?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

No MVVM temos as Views, ViewModels e Models. Toda a lógica de negócio da minha aplicação está em models, onde utilizo as viewModels para gerencia-los, além de binds e comandos que são enviados das Views.

Porém agora me surgiu um problema, eu preciso abrir uma nova janela no sistema, e de quem seria esta responsabilidade?

Sabemos que no "mundo perfeito" do MVVM, a ViewModel não deve se comunicar com a View, porém como posso abrir uma janela sem que a ViewModel não tenha conhecimento da View?

Estou quase para quebrar essa "regra" e abrir uma nova janela da mesma forma que faço no Windows Forms, porém isso impactaria nos testes automatizados e iria contra o princípio do MVVM, então qual a solução? Vale apena quebrar essa regra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vou dar minha opinião se vale a pena quebrar a regra ou não, até porque aqui no SO não é lugar pra ficar dando muita opinião. Vou te dar uma alternativa para não quebrar a regra.

Faça uma interface para encapsular as View e injete na ViewModel.

```
public interface IView
{
    // no lugar de string poderia ser um enumerador também
    bool Show(string viewName);
}

public class ViewManager : IView
{
    public bool Show(string viewName)
    {
        if (viewName == "ListaUsuarios")
        {
            new ListaUsuarios().Show();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    private IView _viewManager;
    public ViewModel(IView viewManager)
    {
        _viewManager = viewManager;
    }

    public void AbrirView()
    {
        if(_viewManager.Show("ListaUsuarios"))
            .....
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu sei que no Stack não é lugar de opiniões, mas nos comentários podemos falar a respeito. Eu acho que a sua solução contorna o problema, mas é um tanto quanto trabalhoso ter que adicionar manualmente as janelas, principalmente se tratando de uma aplicação grande. Mesmo assim você respondeu corretamente, pois a ViewModel não ficou acoplada diretamente com a View.

Comment: Complementando o que escrevi a respeito. Também tenho este problema com a exibição de Dialogs (MessageBox)

Comment: Realmente, é muito trabalhoso, mas não tem muita saída. Ou segue a risca o conceito, ou dá umas escapadas. MsgBox é a mesma coisa, tem que criar uma interface e injetar na VM.

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações, realmente o trabalho é maior, como pretendo trabalhar com equipes pequenas, acho que o MVVM não seria muito adequado em certas ocasiões.